# Netty Connection not working

Tags: java, server, client, protocols, netty

I've the following source: https://hastebin.com/ovekebahij.java

```
bootstrap.group( eventLoopGroup )
                    .channel( serverSocketChannelClass )
                    .option( ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true )
                    .handler( new ChannelInitializer<NioServerSocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel( NioServerSocketChannel nioServerSocketChannel ) throws Exception {
                            callback.onSuccess( preparePipeline( nioServerSocketChannel ) );
                        }
                    });
```

I don't know why but my log says me, that the server is successfully started. Each time I try to connect a client, it says that it cannot connect... anyone an Idea?

Thanks for each contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your server bootstrap method does not block and so close the socket after it was bound.

You should change the code to be:

```
Channel channel = bootstrap.bind(...).sync().channel();
...
channel.closeFuture().sync()
```

This will ensure the method will only return after the socket is closed.